# Assign credentials for CloudFormation without constructor

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am using the Java SDK for CloudFormation. I see that the CloudFormationClient takes in a AWSCredentialsProvider to use the specific credentials for all its requests.

One puzzling question was that can the credentials be set only at the time of creating the cloudFormationClient object? i.e.

```
 new AmazonCloudFormationClient(AWSCredentials awsCredentials);
```

Can I not create a default CloudFormationClient object and then assign the credentials to it? for example:

```
    AmazonCloudFormationClient cloudformation = new AmazonCloudFormationClient();
    AWSCredentialsProvider creds = getMyCreds();
    cloudformation.setCreds(creds);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudformation/AmazonCloudFormationClient.html), there seems to be no methods to set the credentials after you have created an instance of `AmazonCloudFormationClient`. The documentation for the empty constructor ([here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudformation/AmazonCloudFormationClient.html#AmazonCloudFormationClient--)) mentions the search order for a credential provider, and no mentions of anyway in which you could specify them after the object is created.

Answer (score 0):

As @Laf pointed out, there's no method to manually set the creds. I was however, able to find a workaround. You can set the credentials in the request object itself.

```
AmazonCloudFormationClient cloudformation = new AmazonCloudFormationClient();
AWSCredentialsProvider creds = getMyCreds();
DescribeStacksRequest request = new DescribeStacksRequest(...);
request.setRequestCredentials(creds);
cloudformation.describestacks(request);
```